# Apache CSVParser is not working

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons

Consider the following code sample:

```
    private static CSVFormat CSV_FORMAT = CSVFormat.TDF;
    logger.debug("Processing record: {}", line);
    try {
        CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(line,CSV_FORMAT);
        if(parser.getRecords().isEmpty()) continue;
        csvRecord = parser.getRecords().get(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.warn("Skipping line: " + line,e);
        continue;
    }
```

For some reason this isn't parsing. I get the following output:

```
DEBUG:
(OrderParser#parseData:121) - Processing record:
136147091   340834429   4/5/2015 4:35:00
PM  262105109   UFH6285 6   0   0   HWF62 Holmes Humidifier Replacement
Filter  8.99    53.94   0   39.91   0   8.09    0   5.94    5.12        7035997658  Marty   Joe aa3003@mail.com Jess
Dude        555 Main st     Anywhere    CA  900000  1

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

and even though you probably cannot see this via StackOverflow I guarantee there are tabs there. However, the index out of bounds exception occurs at **`parser.getRecords().get(0)`**

If I make a call to `parser.getRecordNumber()` it reports `1`. I don't know if this is due to a character encoding error or what.

As requested, here's some sample input sandwiched inside of a pre tag. There's two lines here, but I'm just sending the second one in:

```
SNumber RecD    Receip_ID   ListingID   Date_Entered    234 ReferenceId QT  QT2 QT3 Title   P456    Product_Rev Sh2687t Product Shipping    Comm    ShipFee PerItemFee  Tax_Cost    Company HoneCode    Bill455 Bill788 Email   Ship468644  Ship6489    Ship654132158   Ship98198   Ship_To_City    Ship_To_State   Ship_To_Zip ShippingMethodId
2644    7775    11457   26894   4/9/2015 9:47:00 AM 247520128   700364  1   0   0   Shark Navigator 14.99   14.99   0   11.75   0   2.25    0   0.99    0       84698   Shawn   Vanloan 3504620ae7f03@mail.com  S Vanloo        166 E Main Rd       Anywhere    NY  12000   1
```

Comment: Well, the output you have above clearly has spaces instead of TAB characters.

Comment: Yeah, like I said: I don't think SO let's people copy n paste tab characters

Comment: Try putting a sample of your CSV into something like pastebin.com and linking here then. Without seeing what your program is reading, it's difficult to debug this. (Also, if it's sensitive customer info, change the names and addresses to something more generic)

Comment: Actually, when you edit it, you can see the tabs, so I centainly believe you. But please edit it yourself and re-paste the output inside the `<pre>` tags - having used a quotation formatting seems to have also added newlines there. Or perhaps the newlines came from your output? How many lines are there in `line`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback: didn't know pre was available to us so I have now added that data in and redacted any sensitive info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter Zheng's answer got me started in the right direction. For me the solution came in the code after calling CSVParser.parse. This actually returns an iterable so I proceeded with the following:

```
CSVParser parser = ... //Any method for obtaining a parser
for(CSVRecord record : parser) {

    //Code for operating on the record here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the apidocs, `parser.getRecords()` parses the file according to the given format and returns the content as a list. The parse-position will be at the end of the input. So another call of `parser.getRecords()` will return an empty list.

Consider parsing the input record wise.

[apidocs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html)

Comment: Ah yes you hit on it. I didn't realize the CSVParser is actually an iterable and that was screwing me up. I believe that the word "Iterator" Should be in the class name, but maybe that's just an excuse for my not checking the API out more thoroughly!